# Was this patent from 1919 reissued? It looks like nothing new was added

Tags: patentability, patent-applications

The following patent was issued in 1919. I believe that the original patent was not renewed. I am trying to understand if the the original patent in all of its definitions was reissued to the new owners and is now locked.

https://patents.google.com/patent/US1448893A/en?q=pelton+wheel&q=F03B1%2f00

The above is a water driven motor called the Pelton Wheel. 
Did the second pair of people reapply for the same patent?

https://patents.google.com/patent/US4950130A/en?q=pelton+wheel&q=F03B1%2f00

So, the former patent of the Pelton Wheel from 1919 cannot be touched anymore? Basically, not one thing new was added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (/a) patent from 1919 is not valid anymore. It cannot be renewed. But it does constitute prior art for new patents.

Starting with the theory:

Everyone can apply for a patent for (almost) everything. The content is analysed only when the grant of the patent is requested. So I could totally apply for a patent for the Pelton wheel right now with exactly the claims from the 1919 patent. But I would not get a grant.

The second patent was granted and the patent office is not stupid, so there probably is something new to the second invention.

How to find out what that is? A patent application normally states prior art, a problem in the prior art and an solution. You can find that in the first paragraphs of a (well written) patent application.

https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/b298f4abcdec036cc1b7/US4950130.pdf (The patent pdf)

The first sentence of the description is "This invention relates to a Pelton turbine."

Then:

> As 
>   is 
>   known, 
>   Pelton 
>   turbines 
>   are 
>   used 
>   for 
>   driving 
>   electricity 
>   generators 
>   or 
>   as 
>   a 
>   direct 
>   drive 
>   for 
>   working 
>   machines. 
>   Generally, 
>   such 
>   Pelton 
>   turbines 
>   include 
>   a 
>   casing 
>   in 
>   which 
>   a 
>   turbine 
>   wheel 
>   with 
>   a 
>   wheel 
>   disc 
>   and 
>   buckets 
>   is 
>   mounted 
>   along 
>   with 
>   a 
>   drive 
>   shaft 
>   which 
>   passes 
>   through 
>   the 
>   casing. 
>   In 
>   addition, 
>   at 
>   least 
>   one 
>   jet 
>   is 
>   provided 
>   for 
>   expelling 
>   fluid 
>   from 
>   a 
>   high 
>   pressure 
>   nozzle 
>   tangentially 
>   of 
>   the 
>   wheel 
>   disc 
>   onto 
>   the 
>   buckets 
>   so 
>   as 
>   to 
>   cause 
>   rotation 
>   of 
>   the 
>   disc 
>   and 
>   drive 
>   shaft. 
>   The 
>   casing 
>   has 
>   also 
>   been 
>   provided 
>   with 
>   a 
>   fluid 
>   outlet 
>   for 
>   removal 
>   of 
>   the 
>   spent 
>   fluid. 
>   Turbines 
>   of 
>   this 
>   type 
>   are 
>   described 
>   in 
>   Ger 
>   man 
>   Pat. 
>   Nos. 
>   12,314; 
>   319,779 
>   and 
>   615,445.

Followed by:

> As 
>   is 
>   known, 
>   the 
>   efficiency 
>   of 
>   a 
>   Pelton 
>   turbine 
>   is 
>   closely 
>   dependent 
>   on 
>   the 
>   success 
>   of 
>   keeping 
>   vagrant 
>   spray 
>   water 
>   away 
>   from 
>   the 
>   turbine 
>   wheel 
>   and 
>   the 
>   buckets. 
>   In 
>   some 
>   cases, 
>   the 
>   drive 
>   shaft 
>   has 
>   been 
>   disposed 
>   on 
>   a 
>   hori 
>   zontal 
>   axis 
>   while 
>   the 
>   lower 
>   region 
>   of 
>   the 
>   turbine 
>   wheel 
>   is 
>   acted 
>   upon 
>   by 
>   the 
>   fluid 
>   jets. 
>   In 
>   these 
>   cases, 
>   the 
>   upper 
>   region 
>   of 
>   the 
>   casing 
>   has 
>   been 
>   provided 
>   with 
>   vertical 
>   metal 
>   sheets 
>   parallel 
>   to 
>   the 
>   plane 
>   of 
>   the 
>   turbine 
>   wheel 
>   while 
>   horizontal 
>   sheets 
>   are 
>   disposed 
>   opposite 
>   the 
>   high 
>   pressure 
>   nozzle 
>   in 
>   order 
>   to 
>   prevent 
>   spray 
>   water 
>   from 
>   reaching 
>   the 
>   upper 
>   region 
>   of 
>   the 
>   casing. 
>   In 
>   Pelton 
>   turbines 
>   used 
>   at 
>   variable 
>   speed 
>   for 
>   driving 
>   working 
>   machines, 
>   these 
>   conventional 
>   baffles 
>   do 
>   not 
>   give 
>   satisfactory 
>   results. 
>   On 
>   the 
>   one 
>   hand, 
>   the 
>   outlet 
>   conditions 
>   from 
>   the 
>   buckets 
>   vary 
>   as 
>   a 
>   result 
>   of 
>   the 
>   large 
>   but 
>   necessary 
>   fluctuations 
>   in 
>   speed 
>   and 
>   load. 
>   This, 
>   in 
>   turn, 
>   results 
>   in 
>   considerable 
>   differences 
>   in 
>   spray 
>   fluid 
>   conditions. 
>   On 
>   the 
>   other 
>   hand, 
>   there 
>   are 
>   great 
>   variations 
>   in 
>   the 
>   amounts 
>   of 
>   fluids 
>   and 
>   these 
>   have 
>   to 
>   be 
>   taken 
>   into 
>   account 
>   in 
>   the 
>   construction 
>   by 
>   providing 
>   high 
>   overflow 
>   levels 
>   so 
>   that 
>   large 
>   quantities 
>   of 
>   fluid 
>   can 
>   be 
>   discharged 
>   without 
>   the 
>   turbine 
>   wheel 
>   becoming 
>   immersed 
>   in 
>   the 
>   sump. 
>   Favorable 
>   conditions, 
>   favorable 
>   efficiency, 
>   can 
>   be 
>   obtained 
>   only 
>   within 
>   narrow 
>   limits 
>   and 
>   when 
>   condi 
>   tions 
>   are 
>   approximately 
>   constant. 
>   **Accordingly, 
>   it 
>   is 
>   an 
>   object 
>   of 
>   the 
>   invention 
>   to 
>   im 
>   prove 
>   the 
>   efficiency 
>   of 
>   a 
>   Pelton 
>   turbine.**
>   (Emphasis added)

So now we know that the inventors knew about prior art and wanted to patent an improvement.

Lets look at the claims, they define the actual scope of the protection. What is not claimed, is not protected.

The independent claims (the other claims are so called dependent claims, so they have limitations regarding the independent claims - they protect **less** than the dependent claim (yes, this makes sense ;-) )) are as follows:

> 1. A 
>      Pelton 
>      turbine 
>      comprising 
>      a 
>      casing 
>      having 
>      a 
>      fluid 
>      outlet; 
>      a 
>      transversely 
>      disposed 
>      partition 
>      in 
>      said 
>      casing 
>      separating 
>      a 
>      spray 
>      fluid 
>      and 
>      outlet 
>      region 
>      from 
>      a 
>      ventilation 
>      region 
>      therein; 
>      a 
>      rotatable 
>      drive 
>      shaft 
>      extending 
>      through 
>      said 
>      casing; 
>      a 
>      wheel 
>      disc 
>      mounted 
>      on 
>      said 
>      shaft 
>      within 
>      said 
>      casing 
>      and 
>      passing 
>      through 
>      said 
>      partition; 
>      a 
>      plurality 
>      of 
>      peripherally 
>      mounted 
>      buckets 
>      on 
>      said 
>      disc; 
>      and 
>      at 
>      least 
>      one 
>      high-pressure 
>      nozzle 
>      in 
>      said 
>      spray 
>      fluid 
>      and 
>      outlet 
>      region 
>      below 
>      said 
>      partition 
>      for 
>      expelling 
>      a 
>      fluid 
>      jet 
>      tangentially 
>      of 
>      said 
>      disc 
>      sequentially 
>      onto 
>      said 
>      buckets 
>      for 
>      rotating 
>      said 
>      disc 
>      and 
>      said 
>      shaft.

and

> 13. A 
>       Pelton 
>       turbine 
>       comprising 
>       a 
>       casing 
>       having 
>       a 
>       fluid 
>       outlet; 
>       a 
>       drive 
>       shaft 
>       extending 
>       through 
>       said 
>       casing; 
>       a 
>       wheel 
>       disc 
>       mounted 
>       on 
>       said 
>       shaft 
>       within 
>       said 
>       casing: 
>       a 
>       plurality 
>       of 
>       buckets 
>       peripherally 
>       mounted 
>       on 
>       said 
>       wheel 
>       disc; 
>       at 
>       least 
>       one 
>       nozzle 
>       for 
>       expelling 
>       a 
>       fluid 
>       jet 
>       tangentially 
>       of 
>       a 
>       lower 
>       portion 
>       of 
>       said 
>       disc 
>       and 
>       onto 
>       said 
>       buck 
>       ets 
>       for 
>       rotating 
>       said 
>       disc 
>       and 
>       said 
>       shaft; 
>       and 
>       a 
>       partition 
>       disposed 
>       in 
>       said 
>       casing 
>       to 
>       separate 
>       an 
>       upper 
>       ventilation 
>       region 
>       from 
>       a 
>       lower 
>       spray 
>       fluid 
>       and 
>       outlet 
>       region 
>       thereof, 
>       said 
>       partition 
>       having 
>       an 
>       opening 
>       for 
>       passage 
>       of 
>       said 
>       disc 
>       therethrough 
>       into 
>       , 
>       said 
>       regions.

I don't know enough about Pelton wheels to judge this, but if you read the patent they will probably explain why these claimed limitations constitute an improvement of the prior art.

This way of looking at a patent helps with (almost) every patent and provides a good first intuition as to what to expect from the patent.

Comment: This is a brilliant reply, Don! You really know the laws.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like  the '130 patent is an improvement to the '893 patent. It cites the older patent and describes improvements. Did you carefully read the specifications and claims. Just because you don't see anything obviously different in the drawing doesn't mean that "not one thing new was added". Figure 3 in particular shows a different arrangement for baffles around the impeller.

Comment: Thank you, Eric. So, could I design my own Pelton Wheel?

Comment: So, all I need to do is add something that has not been tried yet?

Comment: @Owlitz. Both of these patents have expired by now so neither keeps you from making a Pelton Wheel. This doesn't mean there aren't other patents. If you just want to make one for yourself and not sell it, then even active patents wouldn't be a problem. If you like my answer, please accept it by checking the accept control.

Comment: By adding something not obvious you could create a patentable invention. Notmally that might infringe older patents when build (sold), but as they are expired. There might be others though.